# Link function for log-logistic shared gamma frailty model

Tags: survival, link-function, frailty

I've been asked to replicate a study that models an accelerated failure time survival model with a log-logistic distribution and gamma distributed frailty (a 'log-logistic shared gamma frailty model') estimated with the streg command in Stata [1]. We have made some changes to the original model and now want to estimate a quantity of interest, namely expected values, to see if the changes made result in substantially different results. I would do this using the Clarify command in Stata, but unfortunately it does not support this specific model (which the authors of the study I am replicating also acknowledge).

Since I am more familiar with R, my idea was first to replicate the findings there. However, the parfm package, which is roughly analogue to Stata's streg, does not estimate the accelerated failure time model with a log-logistic survival function and a gamma frailty. I have therefore, somewhat inefficiently, extracted the information I need from the estimated model in Stata (the VCV-matrix and the estimated parameters), to estimate expected values in R according to Gary King's simulation approach [2].

To the specific issue; I believe I have all components in place except for the link function. The Stata manual for streg provides the stochastic distribution, but not the link function needed to calculate the expected survival time [3]. According to the streg manual, the log-logistic survival function has the following form:
$$
S(t) = \{1 + (\lambda_{j} t_{j})^{1/\gamma}\}^{-1} 
$$
where $ \lambda_{j}=exp(-\textbf{XB})$ and $\log t = \textbf{XB}$, which implies $t=exp(\textbf{XB})$.

I might be mistaken, but I believe that the frailty is multiplicative and it should therefore be possible to simply multiply the the survival function with the frailty parameter $\alpha_i$.

Thus, my question simply concerns how I should specify the link function to get interpretable values from $y$ generated in the simulation.

I apologize if my question is unclear, but I have no prior experience of working with survival models before being asked to replicate this.

Any input is greatly appreciated,

[1] The Stata syntax reads: 
`stset time.var, failure(fail.var)
streg covariates, dist(llo) frailty(gamma) shared(cluster.var)`

[2] King, G., Tomz, M., & Wittenberg, J. (2000). Making the most of statistical analyses: Improving interpretation and presentation. American journal of political science, 44(2), 347-361.

[3] [http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ststreg.pdf] See page 9 and 25 respectively.

Comment: In survival analysis you are not generally multiplying the survival function by a frailty term, but rather multiplying the hazard function by such a term.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure understanding your question, but I suggest you looking at the statistical model details of parfm in the companion paper

Munda M, Rotolo F, Legrand C. (2012) parfm: Parametric Frailty Models in R. J Stat Soft, 51(12).
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v51/i11

Hope this helps